# JavaFX CEF(Java Chromium Embedded Framework) is not visible with Swing Node in JPanel

Tags: java, swing, maven, javafx

I am trying to use Pandomium (CEF) with JavaFX in Java 11 (Netbeans) with Maven but even though i installed all the dependencies correctly, the swing node does not show me the webbrowser. For some reason Pandomium is working on Java Swing, but unfortunately i can not set the size of my webbrowser.
This is my Maven Dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-swing</artifactId>
            <version>13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-base</artifactId>
            <version>13</version>
        </dependency>
        
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.panda-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>pandomium</artifactId>
            <version>67.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.panda-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>panda</artifactId>
            <version>indev-0.8.87</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Windows x64 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.panda-lang.pandomium-natives</groupId>
            <artifactId>pandomium-natives-win64</artifactId>
            <version>67.0</version>
        </dependency>
        
    </dependencies>
    
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>panda-repository</id>
            <url>https://repo.panda-lang.org/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

This is my JavaFX Code:

```
    @FXML
    private SwingNode swingNode;
    
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
        
        CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
        settings.windowless_rendering_enabled = OS.isLinux();
        CefApp cefApp = CefApp.getInstance(settings);
        CefClient cefClient = cefApp.createClient();

        CefBrowser cefBrowser = cefClient.createBrowser("http://www.google.com", OS.isLinux(), false);
        Component browserUI = cefBrowser.getUIComponent();
        
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(browserUI);
        swingNode.setContent(panel);
    }
```

This is my module-info (My modules-info show me the error: `module de.aria.mavenproject3 reads package org.panda_lang.panda.framework.design.architecture.module from both panda.framework.indev and panda.indev` But the compiler is still able to run my code):

```
module de.aria.mavenproject3 {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires javafx.swing;
    requires javafx.base;
    requires pandomium;
    requires pandomium.natives.win64;

    opens de.aria.mavenproject3 to javafx.fxml;
    exports de.aria.mavenproject3;
}
```

In my XML i only created a Swing Node (fx-id: swingNode) with in a VBox.

Comment: I don't know CEF, but AFAIK a `SwingNode` will only display lightweight Swing components. If CEF uses heavyweight components, it won't be usable with JavaFX `SwingNode`.

Comment: I followed this tutorial: https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?code=Panda-Programming-Language/Pandomium/Pandomium-master/pandomium-win/src/test/java/org/panda_lang/pandomium/win64/WindowsFXTest.java. Can it be possible, that this tutorial is out of date?

Comment: Honestly not sure.